Grainy rendering with TkinterWeb on high-resolution screen in macOS
In a GUI app made with Python 3.13 + tkinter + Tk 8.6, I need to display some content that has extensive formatting. It is in HTML with CSS. I installed the module TkinterWeb, which displays the HTML and allows most of the CSS, but the rendering is very grainy. It's like on a screen from the start of the century.
As an minimal example, here's the usage example from the developer of the module:
from tkinterweb import HtmlFrame #import the HTML browser
import tkinter as tk #python3
root = tk.Tk() #create the tkinter window
frame = HtmlFrame(root) #create the HTML browser
frame.load_website("http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/tkhtml.html") #load a website
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True) #attach the HtmlFrame widget to the parent window
root.mainloop()

This displays a website, and on my Mac you can almost count the pixels. Everything else rendered by tkinter is razorsharp, so it makes full use of the screen resolution; this happens only with the widgets added by tkinterweb.
Attempted solutions
I did the following things suggested by AI:

Adjust the scaling factor in Tk, with root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2.0) and also with different values (anywhere between 0.3 and √5). It doesn't help - makes sense as the problem doesn't seem to be with Tk or tkinter.
Manually set the width and height of the HtmlFrame widget - no luck
Set the environment variables TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 and NSHighResolutionCapable=True – made no difference.

Alternatives
There are other modules that render HTML, but they're not very suitable:

tkhtmlview: does practically no CSS and thus looks awful (though not grainy)
tkinterhtml: not maintained since 2016 (Python 3.5), the creator warns against using it
cefpython: wraps the full Chromium browser, with a large binary executable... Come on
passing the HTML to WebKit (macOS Safari's rendering engine) through the PyObjC module and a series of other modules, and then it renders in a separate window
just opening it in a web browser (not what I'm trying to do).

What could be the cause of this grainy rendering on a high-resolution screen, while tkinter renders all its widgets and text perfectly sharp?

It is not that bad.  It is better to post your output.

Well, I guess it's a matter of taste. But (1) this is the only thing among all apps on my Mac that still looks grainy, (2) other tkinter widgets around it look sharp, so the graininess is very weird and stands out as ugly, (3) the ugliness increases with HTML that's less plain than the example, e.g. with more stylized fonts, and (4) I'm pretty sure it is not the intended behavior of the tkinterweb package.
